# Are there alternatives to the Cassandra node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm using https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver and looks like it is abandoned. No updates for 9 months. I've created PR with a fix to a critical bug and no feedback. Unfortunately my company don't have resources to support it on full time, so option to fork it not available.
We are considering an option to move to another db because we don't see alternatives to `datastax/nodejs-driver` but maybe I missed something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thanks for submitting the PR. Let me reassure you that the driver has not been abandoned. It's more a case of juggling competing priorities and we've had a mad rush as usual for the end of the quarter.

I am assuming you're referring to PR [#383](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/pull/383) for [NODEJS-633](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-633). I can't promise anything but I will contact the engineers on your behalf to bring it to their attention.

As for an alternative, perhaps you might be interested in [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/). It is an open-source data platform that allows you to connect to a Cassandra cluster using APIs developers are already familiar with -- REST API, JSON/Doc API, GraphQL API and more recently [gRPC API](https://stargate.io/2022/01/15/stargate-grpc-the-better-way-to-cql.html).

There are free interactive tutorials on [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) if you'd like to see them in action. They're only about 10 minutes each to complete and they all run in your browser so there's nothing to install: [REST API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/rest), [Doc API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/documents-api), [GraphQL API](https://www.datastax.com/dev/graphql). Cheers!

Comment: @matchish I see that Bret McGuire has responded to your PR and should be good to merge it as soon as you complete the Contributor License Agreement (CLA). Cheers!